# Why this drop downlist in jsp is not running ? ( dropdownlist using loop in jsp )

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu

I want a drop down list in which I don't want to write down every option line by line. In this case my option is year. I am getting the current year and trying to make options of the list from year 1990 to current year using the loop. But it is not wroking...Do I have to write line by line option codes ? I have to run this code on a jsp page.

You can see my jsp code here :

```
<select name = "year_select">
    <%
        int current_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        for(int year = 1990; year<=current_year; year++)
        {
    %>
        <option> <% year %> </option>
    <%  
        }
    %>
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking for help to debug your code, please show your code directly in the post so that it is self contained, and describe in details the problem that you are facing. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) instead of *Scriptlet* in 21st century that is more easy to use and less *error prone*.

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy" value="${today}" var="current_year" />

<select name="year_select">
    <c:forEach begin="1990" end="${current_year}" var="year">
        <option>${year}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Read more about [JSP JSTL Tag Library Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine. Just changed [JSP Scriptlet](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm) to [JSP Expression](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm) `<option> <%=year %> </option>`

```
<select name = "year_select">
    <%
        int current_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        for(int year = 1990; year<=current_year; year++)
        {
    %>
        <option> <%=year %> </option>
    <%  
        }
    %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<%=%>` to display the data in the tags but in your case you are using `<%%>` for the option.
Your code should look like this

```
<select name = "year_select">
    <%
        int current_year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        for(int year = 1990; year<=current_year; year++)
        {
    %>
        <option> <%= year %> </option>//error is here
    <%  
        }
    %>
</select>
```